# How to change value of xml field in a table in oracle server

Tags: xml, oracle

I try to change a value of a field named `ANI_FATHER` from "DAD01" to "DAD01" in a table named `HistEvents` in oracle server.

The field `ANI_FATHER` is found in an XML field named `HEV_DETAILS` in table `HistEvents`, and I don't know how to change value of it.

[image: screenshot of xml field when I do select in an oracle table]

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?><BIRTH Id="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ANI_BIRTHDATE xsi:type="xsd:datetime">2015-12-31T00:00:00</ANI_BIRTHDATE>
   <ANI_MOTHER>MOM01</ANI_MOTHER>
   <ANI_FATHER>DAD01</ANI_FATHER>
   <ANI_NUMGEN>F1</ANI_NUMGEN>
   <ANI_NAIVE xsi:type="xsd:boolean">1</ANI_NAIVE>
   <ANI_DATEIN xsi:type="xsd:datetime">2015-12-31T00:00:00</ANI_DATEIN>
</BIRTH>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test_xml(id number, xml_col xmltype);

insert into test_xml values(1,xmltype(q'~<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?><BIRTH Id="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ANI_BIRTHDATE xsi:type="xsd:datetime">2015-12-31T00:00:00</ANI_BIRTHDATE>
   <ANI_MOTHER>MOM01</ANI_MOTHER>
   <ANI_FATHER>DAD01</ANI_FATHER>
   <ANI_NUMGEN>F1</ANI_NUMGEN>
   <ANI_NAIVE xsi:type="xsd:boolean">1</ANI_NAIVE>
   <ANI_DATEIN xsi:type="xsd:datetime">2015-12-31T00:00:00</ANI_DATEIN>
</BIRTH>~'));
```

1) First way. Looks easier but updateXml function is deprecated.

```
UPDATE test_xml SET xml_col = 
  updateXML(xml_col,  
            '/BIRTH/ANI_FATHER/text()',
            'neW_VALUE')
            WHERE ID =1 ;
```

And check results

```
 SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT XML_COL) FROM TEST_XML WHERE ID= 1;
```

1) Recommended way.

```
UPDATE test_xml SET xml_col =
  XMLQuery('copy $tmp := . modify
            (for $i in $tmp/BIRTH/ANI_FATHER/text()  
             return replace value of node $i
                    with ''neW_VALUE2'') 
            return $tmp'
           PASSING xml_col RETURNING CONTENT)
  WHERE ID =1;
```

[XML Updating Queries to XQuery Update](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/app_depr_upd.htm#ADXDB6044)

[Xpath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz, I'd appreciate your reply & tutorial links. I follow your script & it runs perfectly. Again, thanks a lot for your help! Ed. Jd